# Can different hazard ratios be compared?

Tags: odds-ratio, hazard, medicine

Let's say study 1 finds a HR in group X vs control of 1.5. Study 2 finds a HR of 5.4 in group Y vs control.

As I understand it, HRs involve the rate of the event happening. Since we do not know the amount of time that each study used, we could imagine they are different times, and the HRs aren't comparable.

That is, we can't say X is less bad than Y, assuming the event is something like cancer or heart attack. Is this correct, and does anything change if I refer to the HR/SD of some continuous variable as opposed to a binary outcome?

Perhaps there is some convention in medicine to nearly always define HR as the "events per person years" ratio?